# Matlab: display crosshairs simultaneously on two images in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, matlab-guide

I'm building a MATLAB GUI using GUIDE for processing medical images (brain tumor segmentation on MRI scans). As a preprocessing step, the program coregisters different scans, which looks like this:

[image]

I now want to display crosshairs on both images as a visual check of the coregistration. The crosshairs should be linked to one another, such that they point to the same pixel in both images. Moreover, it should move when hovering over (or clicking on) one of the images. This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Does a build-in MATLAB function exist that can achieve this? Or, if I have to write it myself, how would one tackle this problem?

Comment: I changed the [guide] tag to [matlab-guide] in your post. Please read the tag wikis for the tags you want to use; they are often not what you think they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

The code below is inspired by the answer of BillBokeey, for which I'm very grateful.

First, do steps 0 and 1 of BillBokeey's solution. Then I put this function in my code:

```
    function getMousePositionOnImage(src, event)
    % Fetch the current handles structure
    handles = guidata(src);

    % Get the coordinate IN THE AXES UNITS OF AXES1 (Here I chose to define them
    % as pixels) of the point where the user clicked
    cursorPoint1 = get(handles.axes2, 'CurrentPoint');
    cursorPoint2 = get(handles.axes3, 'CurrentPoint');

    % Get the Position of the first image (We're only interested by the width
    % and height of the axes1 object)
    Img1Pos = getpixelposition(handles.axes2);
    Img2Pos = getpixelposition(handles.axes3);

    XLim1 = get(handles.axes2, 'XLim');
    YLim1 = get(handles.axes2, 'YLim');

    XLim2 = get(handles.axes3, 'XLim');
    YLim2 = get(handles.axes3, 'YLim');

    % Check if inside
    if (cursorPoint1(1)<XLim1(2) && cursorPoint1(2)<YLim1(2) && cursorPoint1(1)>=XLim1(1) && cursorPoint1(1)>=YLim1(1)) 
        Lines1=findobj('Type','line','Parent',handles.axes2);
        Lines2=findobj('Type','line','Parent',handles.axes3);

        if isempty(Lines1)
            % If Lines is empty, we need to create the line objects
            line(XLim1,[cursorPoint1(1,2) cursorPoint1(1,2)],'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2); 
            line([cursorPoint1(1,1) cursorPoint1(1,1)],YLim1,'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2); 

            line(XLim2,[cursorPoint1(1,2) cursorPoint1(1,2)],'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes3); 
            line([cursorPoint1(1,1) cursorPoint1(1,1)],YLim2,'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes3); 
        else
            % If not, we just update the fields XData and YData of both Lines
            Lines1(1).XData=XLim1; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there for clarity
            Lines1(1).YData=[cursorPoint1(1,2) cursorPoint1(1,2)];

            Lines1(2).XData=[cursorPoint1(1,1) cursorPoint1(1,1)]; 
            Lines1(2).YData=YLim1; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there  for clarity

            Lines2(1).XData=XLim2; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there for clarity
            Lines2(1).YData=[cursorPoint1(1,2) cursorPoint1(1,2)];

            Lines2(2).XData=[cursorPoint1(1,1) cursorPoint1(1,1)]; 
            Lines2(2).YData=YLim2; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there  for clarity
        end

    elseif (cursorPoint2(1)<XLim2(2) && cursorPoint2(2)<YLim2(2) && cursorPoint2(1)>=XLim2(1) && cursorPoint2(1)>=YLim2(1))
        Lines1=findobj('Type','line','Parent',handles.axes2);
        Lines2=findobj('Type','line','Parent',handles.axes3);

        if isempty(Lines2)
            % If Lines is empty, we need to create the line objects
            line(XLim1,[cursorPoint2(1,2) cursorPoint2(1,2)],'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2); 
            line([cursorPoint2(1,1) cursorPoint2(1,1)],YLim1,'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes2); 

            line(XLim2,[cursorPoint2(1,2) cursorPoint2(1,2)],'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes3); 
            line([cursorPoint2(1,1) cursorPoint2(1,1)],YLim2,'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes3); 
        else
            % If not, we just update the fields XData and YData of both Lines
            Lines1(1).XData=XLim1; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there for clarity
            Lines1(1).YData=[cursorPoint2(1,2) cursorPoint2(1,2)];

            Lines1(2).XData=[cursorPoint2(1,1) cursorPoint2(1,1)]; 
            Lines1(2).YData=YLim1; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there  for clarity

            Lines2(1).XData=XLim2; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there for clarity
            Lines2(1).YData=[cursorPoint2(1,2) cursorPoint2(1,2)];

            Lines2(2).XData=[cursorPoint2(1,1) cursorPoint2(1,1)]; 
            Lines2(2).YData=YLim2; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there  for clarity
        end

    end
```

Comment: Is the intersection of the lines at the right place?

Comment: The intersection is exactly where I click, so it is!

Comment: The problem is coming from the variables `Img1Pos` and `Img2Pos`

Comment: Does it have the same behaviour with `Img1Pos=get(handles.axes2,'Position')` ?

Comment: no, this didn't work for me, I wasn't able to reach the `if "position is in image?"`

Comment: If nothing works, instead of getting the widt and height of the axes object, you can retrieve the `Xlim` and `Ylim` properties to have your plot boundaries for the lines

Comment: Then fetch the Xlim and Ylim properties with `xlims=get(handles.axes2,'Xlim')` and `ylims=get(handles.axes2,Ylim)` for each axes object. Now instead of `[0 Img1Pos(3)]` you'll have `[xlims(1) xlims(2)]` and instead of `[0 Img1Pos(4)]` you'll have `[ylmis(1) ylims(2)]`

Comment: That seems to work, brilliant! I'll edit my code in a minute. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a Toy GUI in order to show how it works :

[image]

Let's first try to make it work for the first image only. What you want to achieve is :

- When the user clicks on the figure, we want to have access to the location of the mouse click.
- Then we want to check if the click was located inside the first image
- If it is, we want to update the position of the crossbar, which will be represented by two lines overlayed on the image and crossing at the selected point.

### Step 0 : Initial settings

You want to make sure of some details first :

- Make sure you add a call to `hold on` after both your `imshow` calls, otherwise the crossbars will delete your image instead of overlaying on it.

### Step 1 : Getting the position of the mouse click

In your GUI opening function (here it will be `SuperDuperGUI_OpeningFcn`), you want to add a call to :

```
set(gcf, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @getMousePositionOnImage);
```

This will trigger the function `getMousePositionOnImage` everytime the user clicks inside your GUI.

Then, you want to add and implement the function `getMousePositionOnImage` :

```
function getMousePositionOnImage(src, event)

% Fetch the current handles structure
handles = guidata(src);

% Get the coordinate IN THE AXES UNITS OF AXES1 (Here I chose to define them
% as pixels) of the point where the user clicked
cursorPoint = get(handles.axes1, 'CurrentPoint')
```

### Step 2 : Check if the mouse click is inside the first image

Still in the `getMousePositionOnImage` function :

```
% Get the Position of the first image (We're only interested by the width
% and height of the axes1 object)
Img1Pos=get(handles.axes1,'Position')

% Check if inside
if(cursorPoint(1,1)<Img1Pos(3)&&cursorPoint(1,2)<Img1Pos(4)&&cursorPoint(1,1)>=0&&cursorPoint(1,2)>=0)

    % Do stuff

end
```

### Step 3 : If the click was inside the first image, update the position of the crossbar

```
% Check if inside
if(cursorPoint(1,1)<Img1Pos(3)&&cursorPoint(1,2)<Img1Pos(4)&&cursorPoint(1,1)>=0&&cursorPoint(1,2)>=0)


   Lines=findobj('Type','line','Parent',handles.axes1);

   if isempty(Lines)

   % If Lines is empty, we need to create the line objects
   line([0 Img1Pos(3)],[cursorPoint(1,2) cursorPoint(1,2)],'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes1); 
   line([cursorPoint(1,1) cursorPoint(1,1)],[0 Img1Pos(4)],'Color','g','Parent',handles.axes1); 



   else

  % If not, we just update the fields XData and YData of both Lines
  Lines(1).XData=[0 Img1Pos(3)]; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there for clarity
  Lines(1).YData=[cursorPoint(1,2) cursorPoint(1,2)];


  Lines(2).XData=[cursorPoint(1,1) cursorPoint(1,1)]; 
  Lines(2).YData=[0 Img1Pos(4)]; % Unnecessary but I'll leave it there  for clarity


   end




end
```

### Result :

[image]

Now I'll let you do the last part, which involves linking the two crossbars. Instead of only checking if the click was on first image, you'll check both separately. Then, if it is in one of the image, you'll update **both** crossbar to the position of the click in the right axes object

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it and keep you posted.

Comment: I'm sure you'll figure it out. When you do, can you post an answer with the final code?

Comment: I've posted my code in a separate answer. As you can see, it doesn't work perfectly so far. Do you know how I can solve this issue? Thanks a lot!